# Is scrollRangeToVisible(_:) considered slow if a large attributed text is set in UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a question regarding performance and good practice considering scrolling to bottom in `UITextView`.

For example, I have a `UITextView` that displays attributed text, like log messages, with a specific font and color. Note that the log text can include up to 50.000 logs. Every time I append a new log (new attributed string) to existing `UITextView` `attributedText` property, I need to perform a scroll to bottom.

The function below works very well:

```
private func scrollLogTextViewToBottom() {
    let bottomRange = NSRange(location: textView.text.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8), length: 0)
    textView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottomRange)
}
```

I have concerns regarding performance and potential memory (or other resource issues) regarding calling this function to scroll to bottom when UITextView have large quantities of logs, lets say 50.000? Is there a more faster/performance friendly solution to scroll to bottom for each added log, that to always call to get range of the entire UITextView?

Answer (score 0):

So, every time you append a new log (a text), it will be appended in the textview's text as a whole text (without any separation)? I guess this is a good solution.